# Calling cuda function from C

Tags: c, cuda

I've a file A.cu containing function void A(). I've another file test_A.c which calls the cuda function A() and also has function declaration as

```
extern void A();
```

Now I compile and link them as follows

```
nvcc -c -o A.o A.cu 
gcc -o test_A test_A.c A.o /opt/cuda-4.0/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so
```

and I get error like

```
undefined reference to `A'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is probably C++ name mangling. CUDA code is compiled with a C++ compiler, not a C compiler. If you dump the contents of `A.o` you should find a symbol called something like `_Z1Av`, rather than `A` as the C compiler is expecting.

To overcome this, you can use the following declaration inside your `A.cu` file:

```
extern "C" void A(void)
{
    .......
}
```

This will tell the C++ compiler to use C conventions when compiling the code, and a suitably named function will be written to the object file `A.o` which the C compiler and linker can understand.